# Strategy for deal with errors and freeing memory while constructing AST

Tags: compiler-construction, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I have a very simple syntax: expression := number '+' number. I write a recursive descent parser (in C or some other non-garbage collected language, I don't want to use Yacc, ANTLR etc.) that constructs the mini-AST for this grammar. There is no garbage collecting so I must take care of all memory allocations and deallocations.

```
ASTNode *parse() {
  operand1 = parseNumber();
  expect (plus);
  operand2 = parseNumber();

  // Create tree with root (plus) and left and right leaves
  return makeNode (operand1, operand2, plus);
}
```

parseNumber() will parse a number, allocate space for a node, and return the node as a pointer, say *ASTNumber, for the growing AST. makeNode() will knit everything together and return the finished section of the AST.

However, there could be an error while parsing a number, let's say the second number. I have to gracefully unwind the tree at this point because it's now only partially built, and we don't want memory leaks. One strategy is to return a specific error node, say ASTError instead when a call to parseNumber detects an error. The above code with error detection would then look something like this:

```
void parse() {
  operand1 = parseNumber();
  if (operand1 == ASTError) {
     return operand1; // Note its returning ASTError to the caller
  }
     
  if (not expect (plus)) {
     free (operand1);  // Free up the partially constructed AST
     return makeASTError(plus);
  }

  operand2 = parseNumber();
  if (operand2 = ASTError) {
     free (operand1);
     return operand2; 
  }

  // No error, return the finished AST
  return makeNode (operand1, operand2, plus);
}
```

My question: is this a reasonable way to deal with errors during AST construction? I've not seen anything in books or online to suggest what should be done here. If one is programming in Java or even Go, this isn't something you would worry about because any mess you make will be cleared up by the garbage collector.

Another strategy I came up with is to have two parsers, one that checks for syntax errors but does nothing else. If successful it starts the second parser which can now safely build the AST without worrying about errors, hence no concern about freeing partially built trees.

Is what I am doing ok or have I missed something completely obvious?

Comment: If you used bison, you could tell it how to delete a node and it would do that for you in the case of error. Just sayin'.

Comment: Agreed but I'm having to write my own recursive descent algorithm.

Comment: It's pretty common (e.g. in gcc) to use memory pools.  Ephemeral AST objects are allocated in their own pool, which can be freed in constant time, errors or not. It's not worth a lot of effort to manage storage for a condition that will ultimately cause the compiler to shut down anyway.

Comment: `I'm having to write my own recursive descent algorithm` Why? Is this a homework problem. I have been using Prolog with DCGs for years to parse and have never regretted the high hurdle to enter the club. Problems I never would have touched in the past I don't even think twice about doing them. Did I mention that Prolog does garbage collection so no need to track down pointers, unless of course you are working with foreign hooks, but for parsing I have never needed those. :) Maybe you should change the programming language you are using.

Comment: I've used yacc in the past for two biggish projects but I didn't like the difficulties in issuing sensible errors to the user.  If you write your own you have a lot more control. It's not homework, it's a genuine question on what strategies others have used to deal with this problem.

Comment: @Gene I like that idea.